# Assigning blocktrans output to variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to assign the output of a blocktrans block to a template variable.

You can do that using the trans tag like so:

```
{% trans "Some text to translate" as foo %}
```

However you can't do the same with a blocktrans tag. I don't see it in the documentation that you can do this.

Comment: Just kindly asking: You could update the answer to the better one working perfectly with Django 1.9.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django 1.9 added an `asvar` component to `blocktrans` (now called `blocktranslate`).  [An example from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktranslate-template-tag):

```
{% blocktranslate asvar the_title %}The title is {{ title }}.{% endblocktranslate %}
<title>{{ the_title }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ the_title }}">
```

Unfortunately, it seems that before that was added you needed some other way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

That isn't possible with the blocktrans tag.

However, you could use this [captureas templatetag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/545/) to capture the output of blocktrans.

```
{% captureas trans_value %}
    {% blocktrans %}
        This has some stuff in it which will be translated {{ foo }}.
    {% endblocktrans %}
{% endcaptureas %}

{{ trans_value }}
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but I dont know where to put the code you gave the link.

Comment: @olivier-pons You need to define it as a [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/](custom template tag) and then load it in the template

Comment: The accepted answer only works in django v 1.9+. This answer works for < 1.9. You might say my product should be upgraded, and you're right, but upgrading cannot always be scheduled. (also, captureas if more general than just for blocktrans)

Comment: NB that this example as written will include white space; if you want _just_ the output of `blocktrans` stored, do e.g. `{% captureas trans_value %}{% blocktrans %}Foo{% endblocktrans %}{% endcaptureas %}` (i.e. on one line)